# Have they fixed the flash playback issues on the 27 inch iMacs yet?

Tags: macos, mac, flash

I have read very credible reports that there are some issues with cpu intensive tasks like flash playback on the new iMacs.  As soon as they fix it, I am out to get one.  Anyone know if it is fixed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the surprinsingly exhaustive release notes of [Mac OS X 10.6.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3874):

> this update addresses video playback and performance issues for iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009) and iMac (27-inch, Late 2009) computers that may occur in some situations while AirPort is turned on

Additionally reports on [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=811900&page=32) say the update was as advertised and the issues are gone.